# Concurrent GPU kernel execution from multiple processes

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

I have an application in which I would like to share a single GPU between multiple processes.  That is, each of these processes would create its own CUDA or OpenCL context, targeting the same GPU.  According to the Fermi white paper[1], application-level context switching is less then 25 microseconds, but the launches are effectively serialized as they launch on the GPU -- so Fermi wouldn't work well for this.  According to the Kepler white paper[2], there is something called Hyper-Q that allows for up to 32 simultaneous connections from multiple CUDA streams, MPI processes, or threads within a process.

My questions: Has anyone tried this on a Kepler GPU and verified that its kernels are run concurrently when scheduled from distinct processes?  Is this just a CUDA feature, or can it also be used with OpenCL on Nvidia GPUs?  Do AMD's GPUs support something similar?

[1] http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf

[2] http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf

Comment: In answer to the first question you pose, nvidia has published some hyper-Q results in a blog [here](http://blogs.nvidia.com/2012/08/unleash-legacy-mpi-codes-with-keplers-hyper-q/).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link.  That blog post also implies that the K10 GPUs don't have Hyper-Q, while the K20 will.

Comment: That's correct.  You'll note the Kepler white paper link you posted references "GK110" in the title.  The GPU on K20 is GK110.  The GPU on K10 is GK104 (two of them).

Comment: Robert, can you post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In response to the first question, NVIDIA has published some hyper-Q results in a blog [here](http://blogs.nvidia.com/2012/08/unleash-legacy-mpi-codes-with-keplers-hyper-q/).  The blog is pointing out that the developers who were porting CP2K were able to get to accelerated results more quickly because hyper-Q allowed them to use the application's MPI structure more or less as-is and run multiple ranks on a single GPU, and get higher effective GPU utilization that way.  As mentioned in the comments, this (hyper-Q) feature is only available on K20 processors currently, as it is dependent on the GK110 GPU.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's good for the first question, and I guess I'll have to keep searching for the others.

Answer (score -1):

I've run simultaneous kernels from Fermi architecture it works wonderfully  and in fact, is often the only way to get high occupancy from your hardware. I used OpenCL and you need to run a separate command queue from a separate cpu thread in order to do this. Hyper-Q is the ability to dispatch new data parallel kernels from within another kernel. This is only on Kepler.